# Removing datasource version of the page when we remove page version in Sitecore 9.1.1

Tags: sxa, datasource, versions

I have added datasource version of the page through programming. When I am adding any version of the page then it will automatically add version for the datasource items in Sitecore 9.1.1.

Queries :

1. How to remove version of the datasource on a single click of removing version of the page (associated version of the datasource items).
2. Is there any setting in Sitecore for adding/removing version for datasource when we add version of the page. By default, only page version is added and it does not add any version for the datasource.

For more information I am using SXA.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of SXA then:

*How to remove a version of the data source on a single click of removing version of the page (associated version of the data source items).*

There is no such automation on the SXA side, you will need to implement it on your own.

*Is there any setting in Sitecore for adding/removing version for data source when we add a version of the page. By default, only page version is added and it does not add any version for the data source.*

There is no such automation/extension point/setting in SXA which would allow doing that. Again, you need some custom code on your side to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: @Sonu, use voting to show appreciation for answers, not comments. Helps the site.